# Attempted import error: 'uuid' does not contain a default export (imported as 'uuid') In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uuid

**Error is :Attempted import error: 'uuid' does not contain a default export (imported as 'uuid')**

**This is the Code Sample**

```
import uuid from "uuid";
//import * as uuid from "uuid";
import TodoInput from "./components/TodoInput";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";

export default class App extends Component {
state = {
  items: [
    { id: 1, title: "wake up" },
    { id: 2, title: "make breakfast" }
  ],
  id: uuid(),
  item: "",
  editItem: false
};
....
....
```

*What Could be the Reason Behind This?*

Comment: This question appears to be a result from watching [React JS Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBws8MSXN7A) but when running uuid version ^8.3.1 and testing all the answers, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859050/1952287) was the only way to get UUID to work.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Because the `uuid` package has not `default` export, as the error clearly states.

(*it used to exist, but has been [removed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#default-export-removed)*)

> Once installed, decide which type of UUID you need. RFC4122 provides for four versions, all of which are supported here.

(*documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid*)

so you need to choose one of the following

```
import {v1 as uuid} from "uuid"; 
// import {v3 as uuid} from "uuid"; 
// import {v4 as uuid} from "uuid"; 
// import {v5 as uuid} from "uuid";
```

depending on the implementation you want.

---

If you are using an older version of the package you could use one of

```
import uuid from 'uuid/v1'
// import uuid from 'uuid/v3'
// import uuid from 'uuid/v4'
// import uuid from 'uuid/v5'
```

Comment: need: id = uuid()

Answer (score 23):

Once you do `yarn add uuid`, the uuid folder in node_modules contains v1,v2,v3,v4 modules. import any of them according to your choice as uuid.

```
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid'
const id = uuid()
```

This solved my problem. 
versions "uuid": "^7.0.3" and "react": "^16.13.1",

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me.

Firstly, run

```
npm install uuid
```

then

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

To use it just call

```
uuidv4();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This is for other readers, Here `import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';` for `v4 as uuidv4` we can name it as whatever the name ex : `v4 as anyName`. I think this will help someone.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me.

Firstly, run

```
npm install uuid
```

then

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

To use it just call `uuidv4()`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [react-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-uuid)

```sh
npm i react-uuid
```

```
import uuid from 'react-uuid';

const id = uuid();
```

Answer (score 3):

Earlier it was possible to access the default state, which is not available in new release.
Kindly go through the updates: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid.

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

There are other possible access ways provided in package in npm documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Default exports have been removed as stated on the [npm page of UUID](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#default-export-removed).

*From nmpjs.com*

> **Default Export Removed**
>
> uuid@3 was exporting the Version 4 UUID method as a default export:
>
> ```
> const uuid = require('uuid'); // <== REMOVED!
> ```
>
> This usage pattern was already discouraged in `uuid@3` and has been
>   removed in `uuid@7`.

Answer (score 2):

in the command line install uuid:

```
npm i react-uuid
```

in your project:

```
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

const id = uuid();
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have already stated, destructure the variable:

```
const { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
```

For use in your code:

```
const id = uuid();
```

If you are coming across this error in your Jest tests add the following to your moduleNameMapper:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    '^uuid$': 'uuid'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you add to uuid when you import it v4 I think it will work

What I mean is like this

```
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:
import uuid from 'uuid'

This worked for me(For creating random string):
import uuid from 'uuid/v4'

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

```js
import v1 from 'uuid/v1.js' 

const uuid = v1;
```

and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

In the command line, run

```
npm i react-uuid
```

then in your project, try

```
import uuid from 'react-uuid';
const id = uuid();
```

Comment: npm install uuidv4   , import { uuid } from 'uuidv4';

Answer (score 0):

`import uuid from 'uuid/dist/v4'` 
this will work

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes and often times (due to some incomplete/interrupted dependency installations) all you need to do is delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` once more.
Voila (in most cases).

Answer (score -1):

**Create Version 4 (Random) UUIDs**

import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

id:uuidv4(); // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Answer (score -1):

write

```
const uuid = require('uuid');
```

instead of

```
import uuid from 'uuid'
```

Comment: This is not a good practice and doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: My issues were resolved and it is the best practice. That is how you import things in react. Thanks.

Comment: Um...  You sure about that cause the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import) reference differently.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me after removed the **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** and reinstalled the **npm install** and **npm install react-scripts**.

Answer (score -2):

1. yarn add uuid
2. import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid'
3. console.log(uuid());